# Get ID of form when using onsubmit

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Javascript:**

```
function submitComment(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var comment = $('#????').val(); // how do I get the ID?
  // ajax
}
```

**Comment form:**

```
<form id="comment-form[id]" onsubmit="submitComment(event)">
    <input id="comment-input[id]" type="text" placeholder="Comment...">
</form>
```

`[id]` is the variable ID of the specific form. The reason it has an ID is because I have a for loop that displays a whole list of posts, and each post has its own comment form (think Facebook).

What I want to know is how I can get the value (text) of the comment input box when they submit it based on the ID of the form that was submitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `event.target`.

```
var comment = $('input[id^="comment-input"]',e.target).val()
```

This will give you input value.

- `e.target` will give you the current form.
- Then you can use `[^=""]` - attribute starts with selector to find the input element.

---

> how I can get the value (text) of the comment input box based on the ID of the form that was submitted

```
var formID = e.target.id;   //get form ID
var comment = $('#'+formID+' input[id^="comment-input"]').val()
//use $('#parent child') selector.
```

Comment: Let me leave this link to the documentation for later reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/submit

Answer (score 1):

With your setup(HTML/javascript) you can do this with pure javascript like

```
function submitComment(e) {
   var id = e.target.id;
   id = id.match(/\[(.*?)\]/)[1];
   console.log(id);
   var comment  = document.getElementById('comment-input['+id+']').value;
   console.log(comment);
}
```

```js
function submitComment(e){
  var id = e.target.id;
  id = id.match(/\[(.*?)\]/)[1];
  console.log(id);
  var comment  = document.getElementById('comment-input['+id+']').value;
  console.log(comment);
}
```

```html
<form id="comment-form[0]" onsubmit="submitComment(event)">
    <input id="comment-input[0]" type="text" placeholder="Comment...">
  <input  type="submit" placeholder="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I managed to use this by:   var target = e.target.id;
  var id = target.substring(12);
  var comment = $('#comment-input'+id).val();

Comment: @frosty, see my answer which uses a regex

Answer (score 0):

```
function submitComment(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       // e.currentTarget gives you the form element and then you can extract its id
       var formElementId = $(e.currentTarget).attr("id");
       // Then replace the form text with input which will be your comment input id
       var commentElementId = formElementId.replace("form", "input");
       var comment = $(commentElementId).val(); // how do I get the ID?
       // ajax
 }
```

Comment: Oh. This copy/paste. I have updated the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Instead of providing a code-only answer, adding an explanation on how your answer solves the problem will help your readers to learn.

Comment: isim, I have added comments. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
function submitComment(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var comment = $('input[id^="comment-input"]').val();
  // ajax
}
```

Use of jquery start-with selector can be helpful.